# How can i take only some specific data by explode?

Tags: php, explode

In my following code I can explode and get my 3 elements imei,lat,lon as the response was returning only the 3 data separated by `' '`.

```
   $r = socket_recvfrom($sock, $buf, 512, 0, $remote_ip, $remote_port);
    echo "$remote_ip : $remote_port -- " . $buf;

    list($imei,$lat,$lon) = explode(' ', $buf, 3);
```

But what if the response is sending me a lot of data separated by `' '` but still i need only the 3 elements. I don't need the rest data. How can i explode like that?

The data will not be the first three items returned by `explode()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add one more comma to `list()` to ignore the remaining values:

```
list($imei,$lat,$lon,) = explode(' ', $buf);
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/433451)

Or, if the values are in specific places in your array:

```
list($imei, , $lat, , $lon,) = explode(' ', $buf);
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/433455)

The empty placeholders "skip" those values and they are never assigned to a variable.

Comment: what if the returned data is not in order? I mean (needed data) (don't need data) (needed data) (dont need data) ? How can i ignore them?

Comment: Just leave blank spaces where you don't want the value. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: @b0s3 Correct. Thanks for the heads up on that oversight.

Comment: have you tested ? doesn't work `$buf = "hello world stackoverflow bug";
list($imei,$lat,$lon,) = explode(' ', $buf, 3); 
print $imei . "\n";
print $lat . "\n";
print $lon . "\n";`
**output**
`hello
world
stackoverflow bug`
But he don't want **bug**

Comment: Yes, tested and confirmed working. Linked to demos in my answer.

Comment: @JonStirling Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @hhs Did you see my answer? You don't actually need to do anything. The list method by default only populates the parameters you specify. So it doesn't matter how much data is being sent with spaces in it.

Comment: @Hardworker Please don't pimp your answer as a comment in someone else's answer. Especially when it isn't what they are looking for.

Comment: @JohnConde Thanks for the immature downvote to my correct answer. And I am not "pimping" it. Your answer is actually incorrect because by default the list method ignores extra elements of an exploded array. There is no need to add an extra comma or use the '3' argument.

Comment: Read their comments. They are *not* looking for the first three elements. See the second part of my answer. *That's* what they want. Your answer does *not* provide that.

Comment: Umm I was actually looking for a solution like @JohnConde's one. His solution works perfectly. The data are not in order as the question states.

Answer (score 0):

As an extension to @John's answer, there is another php function [`strtok()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php) which is useful in these kind of scenarios

```
$imei = strtok($buf, ' ');
$lat = strtok(' ');
$lon = strtok(' ');
```

Now, suppose if your string

```
$buf = 'test1 test2 test3 test4 test5';
```

`$imei`, `$lat`, `$lon` will be,

```
string 'test1' (length=5)
string 'test2' (length=5)
string 'test3' (length=5)
```

From the php.net manual page,

> Note that only the first call to strtok uses the string argument.
>   Every subsequent call to strtok only needs the token to use, as it
>   keeps track of where it is in the current string. To start over, or to
>   tokenize a new string you simply call strtok with the string argument
>   again to initialize it. Note that you may put multiple tokens in the token parameter. The string will be tokenized when any one of the characters in the argument are found.

Answer (score -1):

Actually you don't need to do anything. If there are extra elements in the exploded array, list won't care.

See:

```
$string = "a b c d e f";
list($a,$b,$c) = explode(' ',$string);
```